# Unity : Get Facebook email by Facebook SDK

Tags: c#, facebook, unity-game-engine

I'm using facebook SDK for my app login, and try to access id, name and email. I follow the reference from facebook developer [FB.LogInWithReadPermissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/reference/current/FB.LogInWithReadPermissions)

```
public void FBLogin(){
    FB.LogInWithReadPermissions (new List<string>(){"public_profile","email","user_friends"}, AuthCallback);
}

private void AuthCallback (ILoginResult result) {
    if (FB.IsLoggedIn) {
        // AccessToken class will have session details
        var aToken = Facebook.Unity.AccessToken.CurrentAccessToken;
        // Print current access token's User ID

        // Print current access token's granted permissions
        foreach (string perm in aToken.Permissions) {
            Debug.Log(perm);
        }
        FB.API ("/me?fields=id,name,email",HttpMethod.GET, GetFacebookInfo);
    } else {
        Debug.Log("User cancelled login");
    }
}

public void GetFacebookInfo(IResult result){
    if (result.Error == null) {
        Debug.Log (result.ResultDictionary ["id"].ToString ());
        Debug.Log (result.ResultDictionary ["name"].ToString ());
        Debug.Log (result.ResultDictionary ["email"].ToString ());
    } else {
        Debug.Log (result.Error);
    }
}
```

Error I get in `Debug.Log (result.ResultDictionary ["email"].ToString ());`

```
KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.
```

Did I miss something ? How can I able to get the email. Thanks a lot.

Comment: When you print the list of granted permissions, does `email` show up? Does the user have a verified email set in their profile?

Comment: @CBroe it only have `user_friends` and `public_profile`

Comment: Well then the user did not grant it ...

Comment: @CBroe how to do the email grant permission ?

Comment: Well the user has to accept it when it is shown in the login dialog. (And if they declined it once already, it will not be asked again automatically, you would have to explicitly re-ask using an additional login dialog parameter. But when you are still in the testing phase, it might be easier to completely remove the app from the user’s settings, and then login again “fresh”.)

Comment: @CBroe I try in Unity, it did not show option to accept

Answer (score 2):

Try to change the line

```
    FB.API ("/me?fields=id,name,email",HttpMethod.GET, GetFacebookInfo);
```

into

```
        FB.API ("/me?fields=id,name,email", HttpMethod.GET, GetFacebookInfo, new Dictionary<string, string> () { });
```

I remember having the same error and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a test user, then you must add the 'email' permission to the test user.

Go to 'facebook for developers' and select your app ('Wizard's Run' for me):

[image]

Then go to 'Test Users'

[image]

Then go to the user that you want to test with and select 'Change permissions this test user granted to app'

[image]

If 'email' isn't already listed, then enter 'email' and Update.

[image]